# How to continuously save Images to Buffer while my app camera starts in android?

Tags: android, camera

In my application I want to save Images to Buffer as soon as user starts the camera to capture the frames of camera before the user try to capture an image.  please suggest me a specific way to achieve this in android.

Answer (score 0):

In the old camera api you can access the preview frame data relative easy.
From Android 5.0 has introduced the camera2, which is a lot more complicated to set up the correct handlers and states.

Now the Android 7.0 is released the main question is: are you fine to use old, deprecated code or not? Since some of our Android phones still use 4.2 and 4.4 other 5.0a and 6.0 for me is fine, but I don't know your case.

Here I have just removed a custom color, like how is removing the green screen, but if the user touch the preview screen it will select the desired color, like  a brown or a blue, whatever.

```
private class CameraPreviewCallback implements Camera.PreviewCallback {

    private int curColor, curRed, curGreen, curBlue;

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        // conversion:
        decodeYUV420SP(mRgb, data, mSurfWidth, mSurfHeight);

        // check if need an update for the selected color
        if (mRequestColorUpdate) {
            int arrayIndex = mTouchY * mSurfWidth + mTouchX;
            mChoosedColor = mRgb[arrayIndex];
            btRecordVideo.setBackgroundColor(mChoosedColor);
            mRequestColorUpdate = false;
            updateBackgroundRemovalLimits();

           // do my stuff, not important here
        }
        // remove background:
        for (int i = 0; i < mRgb.length; i++) {
            curColor = mRgb[i];
            // split:
            curRed = Color.red(curColor);
            curGreen = Color.green(curColor);
            curBlue = Color.blue(curColor);

            if ((minRed <= curRed) && (curRed <= maxRed) && (minGreen <= curGreen) && (curGreen <= maxGreen) && (minBlue <= curBlue) && (curBlue <= maxBlue)) {
                // set alpha to 0 bitwise:
                mRgb[i] = curColor & 0x00FFFFFF;
            }
        }

        // update the modified preview screen:
        mBitmap.setPixels(mRgb, 0, mSurfWidth, 0, 0, mSurfWidth, mSurfHeight);
        if (ivPreviewModified != null) {
            ivPreviewModified.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

You have to add to camera:

```
 camera.setPreviewCallback(new CameraPreviewCallback());
```

And the camera initialized like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //
    camera = Camera.open();
    startPreview();
}
```

And this is from stackoverflow :)

```
public class YuvToRgb {

    //  Byte decoder : ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   public static final void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        // Pulled directly from:
        // http://ketai.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ketai/src/edu/uic/ketai/inputService/KetaiCamera.java
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0)
                    r = 0;
                else if (r > 262143)
                    r = 262143;
                if (g < 0)
                    g = 0;
                else if (g > 262143)
                    g = 262143;
                if (b < 0)
                    b = 0;
                else if (b > 262143)
                    b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }
}
```